# Who arranges/creates the different segments(stack,heap,code segment, data segment) of a program

Tags: linux, memory-management, assembly

While going through different segments of a program, I have some doubt about who creates this segments.
My understanding is the assembler creates this different segments while creating the assembly code and the when loading into the virtual memory the loader creates the virtual address space for all the segments and stores them in the virtual memory.

Please help me in understanding it.

Comment: Generally it's done by the compiler, the assembler, the linker and the operating system, all cooperating about it. But it also depends a lot on the target, for example for embedded systems without operating system or with a small real-time operating system, it could partly be done by the compiler/assembler with the final segmentation by the linker.

Comment: It isn't quite so simple. You tell the compiler what your target and memory model is (even if you just accept the defaults). Your compiler than creates the segments that conform to your type of program being compiled in a given target and memory model. In the default case, you will generally get a data segment, rodata segment, bss segment, code segment, stack segment, you also get extra memory segments f & g. The limits are predefined. If you change your target of compile with the huge memory model, that will change as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compilers translate a program's executable statements into CPU instructions, and declarations of static data are translated into machine-specific data specifications. To create an executable file, **the system linker aggregates the instructions and the data into distinct segments**. All of the instructions go into one segment traditionally called text.Meanwhile, the data are arranged in two segments. One is called data, for the initialized static data and literal constants, and the other, bss, for the uninitialized static data.

http://www.ualberta.ca/CNS/RESEARCH/LinuxClusters/mem.html

Good site describing all the memory management process involved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the assembler generates the individual segments, but you specify them in your code using labels, for instance the .data directive tells the assembler that we've reached the data segment.

Comment: If using `gcc/gas`, are you saying `gas` determines the segment layout and not `gcc`?

Comment: No, I interpreted this specifically as writing raw assembler. If using higher-level language, my answer does not apply.